Customized phone app not default call app
I want to make customized phone app from not default call phone. But I can't find Library cusomized called(no default call app)  at flutter or android studio.
But I can't find Library cusomized called(no default call app)  at flutter or android studio.

So do you want VoIP call or native call? what do you mean by "customized called(no default call app)"?

It means native call. I want applying to my cusomized ui

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
